# Convert plain string to MAC Address format in swift

Tags: swift

How can I convert a plain string to macadress format. I just need a utilty function to convert plain string to macadress format.

Ex:
input: ECDA3B15FFB0
output: EC:DA:3B:15:FF:B0

I've found many in other languages, but not in swift